# Looking for the proper way to clone

Tags: java, clone

I have a class `Calle` with a `String nombre;` and a `int addr;`. But, the `clone` method I've made is giving me the wrong values.

```
public class Calle{
    String nombre;
    int addr;

    public Object clone(){
        return this;
    }
}

Calle c1 = new Calle("a",1);
Calle c2 = c1.clone();
c2.setAddr(3);

System.out.println(c1.addr); // value wrong
```

Why is the value wrong?

Comment: b/c you aren't actually cloning.  you need to actually make a new Object and return it

Comment: Clone is not a special method, it is like any other method as far as Java is concerned. You have to code it to actually clone the object, not just `return this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case you can use standard shallow clone method provided by Object. As long as String is immutable and int value will be copied, there is no reason in overriding copying logic. Just make it visible.

```
public Object clone(){
    return super.clone();
}
```

[Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface also should be implemented.

Comment: standard clone copy all values?

Comment: Yes, it makes a shallow copy. Without copying child objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your clone method is wrong because it's not really cloning anything, it's just returning the same object.  The `clone` should always be a **new** object with the same values as the original.

In this case it looks like you already have a copy constructor, so just use that to create the new `Calle` and return it.

```
public Object clone(){
    return new Calle(this.nombre, this.addr);
}
```

Comment: That's it.  This will create the new Calle, fill in the same values as the object you are cloning, and will return it

Answer (score 1):

Your clone method is wrong because it's not really cloning anything, it's just returning the same object.

```
 public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    return super.clone();
}
```

This cloning will only do shallow cloning .If you want deep cloning, you need to write your won logic to clone.